# Run PHP (in console) with Geany

Tags: command-line, php, gnome-terminal, php-cli

I can manually go to terminal and write `php filename.php` and it will run it successfully for me. I just need to know how I can do it from Geany.

Proof:

[image]

`gnome-terminal -e "php %f"` is what I had in mind, but it doesn't work, gives an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try just `php %f` - the default Geany execution environment already already knows to use your session's `x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: @steeldriver Tried this, didn't run at all? Where is it supposed to output?

Comment: It should pop up a terminal window when you invoke the execute action. Where did you write `php "%f"`? it should go in the `Execute` box under the `Build` --> `Set build commands` menu item. _Note I missed the double quotes in my previous comment._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Use the command `php "%f"`. It should automatically run it in the little window on the bottom.